# Change width of scrollbars

Tags: c#, windows, resize, size, scrollbar

I am working on a program for touchscreens. I am using c# and Visual studio 2008. Is there any way to change the width of the scrollbars? I know that i can change in Display Properties of Windows. But i only want in my programm not in the complete system. Thanks for ya help!

Answer (score 7):

Check this out:

[Winforms - Adjust width of vertical scrollbar on CheckedListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819462/winforms-adjust-width-of-vertical-scrollbar-on-checkedlistbox)

Worth mentioning too:

[.NET Compact framework - make scrollbars wider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964026/net-compact-framework-make-scrollbars-wider)

More of the same, but this time with a better solution through the use of the scrollbar control:

[Change the width of a scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7224/114029)

Another one in which the guy teaches how to create your own scrollbar control (interesting):

[Set the Scrollbar width of a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2511568/114029)

The last one (worth trying):

[Is there a way to get the scrollbar height and width for a ListView control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3205038/114029)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to search for scrollbar instances in the form/control's controlcollection and then simply update the width value.

```
foreach(Control ctrl in dataGridProducts.Controls)
    if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(VScrollBar))
        ctrl.Width = 100;
```

This works on Windows CE with dot net compact framework