# C# - ScrollBar in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, scrollbar

Is that possible **expand(make wider)** scrollbar in DataGridView?

Is there a method that is responsible for that?

[image]

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593915/change-width-of-scrollbars

Answer (score 1):

If you are using DataGridView within Windows Forms then there is a property named ScrollBars, you can have options there, choose what suits your requirement.

If you are using ASP.NET put your DataGridView within a div i.e.

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: scroll">your GridView</div>
```