# How to make a winforms scrollbar wider using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I asked this over at StackOverflow and someone suggested I try here, so...This program uses winforms and c# (no wpf). I have a panel with buttons on it and getting it to scroll is no problem. However, when the program is on a hi-resolution touch screen -- like a Surface 7 -- trying to touch in the exact right spot to get it to scroll is hit and miss. I've searched and have yet to find a way to make the grab area (so to speak) of a vertical scroll bar wider so that when you touch the screen, the control actually picks up the event. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: That's definitely a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Your question is explicitly out of scope.  You need to edit your Stack Overflow question so it can be reopened

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change width of scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593915/change-width-of-scrollbars)

Answer (score 0):

This can be a super user question if youre looking for a tool to make it wider for all apps because it could be considered as an accessibility.

If you're writing an app

Vertical Scroll Bar Width

```
 System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
```

Horizontal Scroll Bar Width

```
 System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight;
```

Duplicate of 
     [Change width of scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593915/change-width-of-scrollbars)

Comment: You may need to write your own control that inherits from one of these classes or use a ready made solution. https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/styling-guide-scrollbar-resizing

Comment: Wasn't me.  My guess would be because you didn't really answer the question.

Comment: @LarsTech I didn't see anyone else comment or add information to help you. It's weird. Click the link that has the duplicate question. It should help you. I think you may end up creating your own control or using a 3rd party. You can also consider Wpf. You can try to host a WinForm control in your Wpf app (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-windows-forms-control-in-wpf)

Comment: I didn't post the question.