# Custom scrolling in Winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

I am developing an application that will use touch screens to navigate for use in a warehouse environment.

There is a need to present a list to the users and because this list could be quite long, the user will at some point need to scroll down the list.

As you all know the system scroll bars for panels and textboxes etc is quite small and I would like to know if I can either resize the controls that make up the scroll bar (the little arrows at the top and bottom, and the place holder bar in the scroll bar itself), or if I can create a couple of buttons that can scroll up and down my control for me?

Thanks,
Karl

Comment: This was the shortfall of WinForms for which they developed WPF :-)

Comment: This isn't just a problem with *your* app, *any* window that's displayed on that touch panel will be hard to use.  So just change the system setting and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer pulled from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593915/change-width-of-scrollbars).

Check this out:

[Winforms - Adjust width of vertical scrollbar on CheckedListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819462/winforms-adjust-width-of-vertical-scrollbar-on-checkedlistbox)

Worth mentioning too:

[.NET Compact framework - make scrollbars wider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964026/net-compact-framework-make-scrollbars-wider)

More of the same, but this time with a better solution through the use of the scrollbar control:

[Change the width of a scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7224/114029)

Another one in which the guy teaches how to create your own scrollbar control (interesting):

[Set the Scrollbar width of a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2511568/114029)

The last one (worth trying):

[Is there a way to get the scrollbar height and width for a ListView control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3205038/114029)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own scroll buttons and programatically scroll like so:

```
myPanel.VerticalScroll.Value++;
```